# How to Change Select Query Value to Text using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ignition

Take a look at the following query. How do you display Column 'Action' as text.
If the result of 'Action' is LEQ 0 then dipslay the text "Crash" and if 'Action'
is GRT 0 display the text "Hold"?

```
SELECT col1 AS Action
FROM vdk
WHERE t_stamp Between "{StartTime}" AND "{EndTime}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CASE WHEN ... ELSE ... END](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) and select **from** your set (query):

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN Action <= 0 THEN 'Crash' ELSE 'Hold' END) as ActionText
FROM (
    SELECT col1 AS Action
    FROM vdk
    WHERE t_stamp Between "{StartTime}" AND "{EndTime}"
) q
```

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring the answer above, since i don't see the necessity to add a query to an alias table. I think this should work the other answer should work too btw, but its a little more complicated query for no given reason.

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN col1 <= 0 THEN 'Crash' ELSE 'Hold' END) AS Action
FROM vdk
WHERE t_stamp Between "{StartTime}" AND "{EndTime}"
```

Comment: He wants to use `Action` (which is an alias) for the `CASE WHEN ...` statement.

Comment: i think both are valid answers, since no calculation/processing is done on alias Action

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial answer, but the question is old and OP recently edited it with a "simpler" version of what he was after. You can see it in the edits.

Comment: Ohh i understand now! anyways, for the new question both are right!

Comment: In a similar application we use Ignition's Power Table Component and it's Extension Function - configureEditor to allow a user to select from a Table Drop Down List "NULL", "Hold" or "Crash" and have it entered into the Database.  See the following answer for this config.

Answer (score 0):

This application is similar to my first question and I thought it might help someone else down the the road.
User can select from a Table's Drop Down List a set of options to enter a value into the Database.

Using Ignition's Power Table Component's Extension Function configureEditor with the following script.
This script sets up the Drop Down List.

```
if colName == 'Action':
   return {options': [(0, 'Null'), (1, 'HOLD'), (2, 'CRASH')]}
```

Along with the same Power Table's Extension Function onCellEdited script.
This script enters the selection as a value into the database.

```
#onCellEdited Upadte Query
row = rowIndex
col = colIndex
colName = colName
value = newValue

ndx = self.data.getValueAt(row,0)
query = "UPDATE vdk SET %s = ? WHERE ndx = ?" % colName
system.db.runPrepUpdate(query,[value,ndx],'history')
system.db.refresh(self.data)
```